# Modificar tabla para asignar esquema de partición

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla a la cual quiero asignar un esquema de partición, ya tengo los FILEGROUP y los FILES asignados inclusive la función y el esquema de partición creados pero cuando quiero asignar el esquema el SQL me manda un error . Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
use dbsav512

--Se crean los grupos de archivos en la base de datos dbsav512
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Enero
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Febrero
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Marzo
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Abril
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Mayo
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Junio
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Julio
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Agosto
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Septiembre
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Octubre
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Noviembre
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILEGROUP Dciciembre
--Se crean los archivos y se añaden al grupo de archivos correspondiente
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Enero', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Enero.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP ENERO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Febrero', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Febrero.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP FEBRERO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Marzo', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Marzo.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP MARZO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Abril', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Abril.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP ABRIL
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Mayo', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Mayo.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP MAYO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Junio', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Junio.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP JUNIO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Julio', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Julio.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP JULIO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Agosto', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Agosto.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP AGOSTO
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Septiembre', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Septiembre.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP SEPTIEMBRE
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Octubre', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Octubre.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP OCTUBRE
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Noviembre', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Noviembre.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP NOVIEMBRE
ALTER DATABASE dbsav512
ADD FILE
(NAME='Diciembre', FILENAME='C:\Datos\Diciembre.ndf',
SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=3GB, FILEGROWTH=25%
)TO FILEGROUP DCICIEMBRE
--Se crea la función de partición
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION FuncionDeParticion(datetime)
AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES('20160201','20160301','20160401','20160501',
'20160601','20160701','20160801','20650901',
'20161001','20161101','20161201')
--Se crea el esquema de partición
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME EsquemaDeParticion
AS PARTITION FuncionDeParticion TO
(ENERO, FEBRERO, MARZO, ABRIL, MAYO, JUNIO,
JULIO, AGOSTO, SEPTIEMBRE, OCTUBRE,
NOVIEMBRE, DCICIEMBRE)
```

Trato de modificar la tabla de la siguiente manera, pero el SQL no me deja. Espero puedan ayudarme

```
 --Se modifica el esquema de la tabla
ALTER TABLE tVenta()
ON EsquemaDeParticion(venta_Fecha)
```

Comment: *el SQL me manda un error*. Ok, pero, ¿cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: El error es el siguiente:                                                                                     Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '('.

Answer (score 1):

Para tomar una tabla existente y particionar sus datos, el proceso es un poco más complicado. Y para darte una respuesta más precisa, necesitaría saber más en cuanto a la estructura de tu tabla y sus claves e índices.

El siguiente "problema" es que hay más de una manera de particionar los datos. Y dependiendo de la opción que escojas, esto afecta como defines la clave primaria y el clustered index. Determina si solos particionas los datos, o todos los índices también. Y, esto, a su vez, tiene un impacto en el rendimiento de diferentes consultas. Determinar cuál opción es la mejor es muy difícil sin entender cómo consultas los datos.

De modo que me limito a presentarte 2 opciones básicas, y te tocará hacer la investigación y determinar cuál es la más apropiada para ti.

Para las opciones que te presento voy a asumir que tu tabla tiene una estructura básica similar a la siguiente:

```
create table tVenta (
  VentaId int not null constraint tVentaPk primary key,
  OtraColumna1 varchar(50),
  OtraColumna2 varchar(50),
  venta_Fecha datetime not null
);
```

También asumo que tienes un `Filegroup` por defecto que se llama `[PRIMARY]`.

**Opción #1 - Clave primaria particionada**

```
alter table tVenta
drop constraint tVentaPk;

alter table tVenta
add constraint tVentaPk
primary key (venta_Fecha, VentaId) -- puedes cambiar el órden de las columnas
on EsquemaDeParticion(venta_Fecha);
```

**Opción #2 - Clave primaria no particionada**

```
alter table tVenta
drop constraint tVentaPk;

create unique clustered index tVentaPartitionedClusteredIndex
on tVenta (venta_Fecha, VentaId) -- puedes cambiar el órden de las columnas
on EsquemaDeParticion(venta_Fecha);

alter table tVenta
add constraint tVentaPk
primary key (VentaId)
on [PRIMARY]; -- si se te olvida esta parte, vas a recibir un error.
```

**Notas adicionales**

Lo anterior no toma en cuenta que tal vez tengas otras tablas con claves foráneas definidas hacia tabla `tVenta`. De ser el caso, para que funcione, tienes que eliminar esas claves foráneas antes de la operación, y luego volver a crearlas.

También, estoy pasando por alto el hecho de que si tienes otros índices definidos en la tabla `tVenta`, tendrás que evaluar si deseas particionarlas también (o sea, asignarles el esquema de partición). De ser el caso, tendrás que volver a crear esos índices incluyendo la columna `venta_Fecha` en su definición.

El punto es que la partición de los datos es un tema muy amplio y complicado. Si ya estás experimentando dificultad en definirla correctamente con tus tablas existentes, veo como poco probable el que puedas sacarle el máximo rendimiento. La partición de los datos no es una solución mágica que automáticamente mejora el rendimiento de las consultas. Requiere un buen entendimiento de los datos, las consultas envueltas y la manera como SQL Server las maneja con diferentes configuraciones.

**Referencias interesantes**

- [How to partition an existing non-partitioned table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48011/how-to-partition-an-existing-non-partitioned-table)
- [SQL Server Primary Key vs Clustered Index, Part 3: Table Partitioning and Partition Key Selection](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-primary-key-vs-clustered-index-part-3-mb01/#.WB1gcvorKUk)
- [Does the partition key also have to be part of the primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/does-the-partition-key-also-have-to-be-part-of-the-primary-key)